# Restrict adding a new admin to super admin

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, devise, rails-admin

I'm using Rails_Admin and Devise. I have an admin model with a column 'super' that is a boolean.  I would like to prevent admins from adding new admins unless they are a super admin.  I have already hidden the admin model in rails_admin to all who are not super admins. However, I can still add a new admin by typing in the route localhost:3000/admin/admins/new. How can I block this route?  They should also not be able to edit or delete other admins.

Comment: I've used Devise and overridden their controllers to add my own admin/super-admin functionality, but haven't used Rails_Admin. Do you have access to their controllers to do something like a before_action filter? If so, you could create a filter before the create action to check if the new user is set to be admin and if the current_user is a super-admin and, if not, deny the request.

Answer (score 1):

You could try redirecting them in your routes.rb depending on their role.  Something like this:

```
  authenticate :user, lambda { |u| u.roles.include? :superadmin } do
    get '/admin/user/new', to: redirect('/admin')
  end
  mount RailsAdmin::Engine => '/admin', as: 'rails_admin'
```

Comment: Thank you for your solution. It looks promising. I think it just needs some tweaking. The admins have a boolean, super_user.  So it should check if that is true. Like current_admin.super_user == true.  I have tried this: `authenticate :user, lambda { |u| u.super_user == true } do
    get '/admin/user/new', to: redirect('/admin')
  end`  It doesn't throw an error, but it also still allows me to hit the route.  I'm not %100 on what lambdas are actually doing, so going to investigate that.  Again, thank you, at least it's a new direction.